# Iphone newb Question - How to export information to a website?

Tags: iphone

I am a new iphone developer and was wondering if I could get some help with some code.  I just want to know how to export basic character strings and variables to a website to be used by a third-party program.  edited*(how do I send it as an http request to a web server?)

I am a fairly new programmer and am wondering if there is some sort of basic code line that sends a user input as an email/http request to a specific email/web address?

Basically, if I had something as basic as:

```
int variableOne;
int variableTwo;
```

What code would I use to export these variables?

Comment: You have to be more specific. You mean POST them to a website?

Comment: How about posting it as an HTTP request to a web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) framework, its best in business for iPhone/iPad

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the third-party's API.  If it uses JSON, you should use a JSON library such as [touchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSONHowTo).  If it uses XML, you should probably use [NSXML classes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html).  Either way, you can use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) to actually make the connection.